# Install libvirt plugin on vagrant version >= 1.8.1 on Windows PC

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, vagrant, libvirt

I ran into a problem installing libvirt plugin at vagrant version 1.8.1 using the following command:

```
vagrant plugin install --verbose vagrant-libvirt
```

This is the output I get:

> Installing the 'vagrant-libvirt' plugin. This can take a few
>   minutes... Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources.
>   Using `source` more tha n once without a block is a security risk, and
>   may result in installing unexpect ed gems. To resolve this warning,
>   use a block to indicate which gems should come  from the secondary
>   source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle con fig
>   disable_multisource true`. Fetching source index from
>   http://gems.hashicorp.com/ Fetching gem metadata from
>   https://rubygems.org/.......... Fetching version metadata from
>   https://rubygems.org/...... Fetching version metadata from
>   https://rubygems.org/.. Resolving dependencies....... Using builder
>   3.2.2 Using bundler 1.10.6 Using ffi 1.9.10 Using childprocess 0.5.9 Using erubis 2.7.0 Using excon 0.45.4 Using formatador 0.2.5 Using
>   fog-core 1.36.0 Using multi_json 1.11.2 Using fog-json 1.0.2 Using
>   mini_portile 0.6.0 Using nokogiri 1.6.3.1 Using fog-xml 0.1.2 Using
>   json 1.8.3 Installing ruby-libvirt 0.6.0 with native extensions
>
> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160225-6712-1ph8sm p.rb extconf.rb
> ```
>
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>           --with-libvirt-include
>           --without-libvirt-include
>           --with-libvirt-lib
>           --without-libvirt-lib
>           --with-libvirt-config
>           --without-libvirt-config
>           --with-pkg-config
>           --without-pkg-config extconf.rb:73:in `': libvirt library not found in default locations (Runti meError)
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/Users/Z003H1ZT/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/ruby-l ibvirt-0.6.0 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   C:/Users/Z003H1ZT/.vagrant.d/gems/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0
>   /ruby-libvirt-0.6.0/gem_make.out Bundler, the underlying system
>   Vagrant uses to install plugins, reported an error. The error is shown
>   below. These errors are usually caused by misconfigured plugin
>   installations or transient network issues. The error from Bundler is:
>
> An error occurred while installing ruby-libvirt (0.6.0), and Bundler
>   cannot cont inue. Make sure that `gem install ruby-libvirt -v '0.6.0'`
>   succeeds before bundling.

Other people having issues installing libvirt plugin on newly updated vagrant [here](https://github.com/pradels/vagrant-libvirt/issues/534).

As a second approach I tried to install the plugin offline with a downloaded vagrant-libvirt gem file using

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt-0.0.32.gem
```

But there also appears an error:

> Installing the 'vagrant-libvirt-0.0.32.gem' plugin. This can take a
>   few minutes. ..
>   C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:439:in
>   `resolv e_for_zero': Unable to resolve dependency: 'vagrant-libvirt (=
>   0.0.32)' requires  'fog-libvirt (~> 0.0.1)' (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:3
>   50:in`resolve_for'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:1
>   96:in `resolve'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/request_set.r
>   b:358:in`resolve'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency_in
>   staller.rb:473:in `resolve_dependencies'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency_in
>   staller.rb:373:in`install'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/b
>   undler.rb:129:in `block in install_local'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/b
>   undler.rb:284:in`block in with_isolated_gem'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/user_interact
>   ion.rb:45:in `use_ui'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/b
>   undler.rb:283:in`with_isolated_gem'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/b
>   undler.rb:126:in `install_local'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/p
>   lugin/manager.rb:47:in`install_plugin'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/comma
>   nds/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:37:in `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/a
>   ction/warden.rb:34:in`call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/a
>   ction/builder.rb:116:in `call'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/a
>   ction/runner.rb:66:in`block in run'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/u
>   til/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/a
>   ction/runner.rb:66:in`run'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/comma
>   nds/plugin/command/base.rb:14:in `action'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/comma
>   nds/plugin/command/install.rb:32:in`block in execute'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/comma
>   nds/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in `each'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/comma
>   nds/plugin/command/install.rb:31:in`execute'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/plugins/comma
>   nds/plugin/command/root.rb:56:in `execute'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/c
>   li.rb:42:in`execute'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/lib/vagrant/e
>   nvironment.rb:302:in `cli'
>           from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.1/bin/vagrant:1
>   74:in`'

Are there some suggestion what I am doing wrong or a different approach?

Comment: This is still a thing on windows -_-'